# detect Baseline/Profile of mp4 video

Tags: mp4

How to find out the baseline/profile of a mp4 video file?

The unix tool `file` only says ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
But there are differences between mp4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) is a great tool for getting video information, including profile, and can output a variety of easily parsed formats.

Answer (score 5):

you could use the [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) tool on the file. Output is like this:

```
...
Codec/CC                                 : avc1
Codec profile                            : Main@L3.0 
Codec settings                           : 2 Ref Frames
Codec settings, CABAC                    : No
...
```

or if you want to find out without an external tool you would need to parse the MP4 up to /moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stsd/avc1/avcC . In the avcC box you can find the SPS (sequence parameter set)  and that data structure contains the fields profile_idc and level_idc. Annex A of the 14496-10 specification then allows you to translate these two fields to actual level and profile.

Comment: Just a side note: mediainfo has an option of XML output, simplifying things somewhat.